# Exclusive react state hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have some boolean react state hooks, where only one should be allowed to be `true` at a time. Their states depend on a string variable being passed through. I currently have this code, which works fine:

```
  const [a, setA] = useState(false);
  const [b, setB] = useState(false);
  const [c, setC] = useState(false);
  const [d, setD] = useState(false);


    if (foo == "string1") {
      setA(true);
      setB(false);
      setC(false);
      setD(false);
    }
    if (foo == "string2") {
      setB(true);
      setA(false);
      setC(false);
      setD(false);
    }
    if (foo == "string3") {
      setC(true);
      setA(false);
      setB(false);
      setD(false);
    }
    if (foo == "string4") {
      setD(true);
      setA(false);
      setB(false);
      setC(false);
    }
```

I'm using them for conditional styling, so they have to be boolean (maybe I need to rethink my approach?).

However, it's very verbose. Is there a better way to write this?

Comment: Why don't you have a single state that takes one of four values?!

Comment: Why do you need any state other than `foo`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a single state variable instead, whose value contains the currently "active" one:

```
const [active, setActive] = useState();

if (foo === 'string1') {
  setActive('a');
}
if (foo === 'string2') {
  setActive('b');
}
// etc
```

Comment: I should've mentioned - I need them to be boolean because I'm using them for conditional styling. Maybe I need to rethink this approach

Comment: @jlinks - With the above, if you used to have `a` as a condition, you just change it to `active === "a"` instead. For instance, `className={a ? "x" : "y"}` becomes `className={active === "a" ? "x" : "y"}`. That seems like an overall win vs. have multiple state members you could easily end up making non-exclusive. :-) Or you can apply my "convenience" thing from my answer to this one as well: `const a = active === "a"; const b = active === 'b";`

Comment: I didn't think of that approach, thank you for the patient explanation! still new to some of this.

Comment: The original multi-boolean-state based approach (with `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`) also has the disadvantage that react does *not* guarantee multiple `setState` calls to be committed atomically. Multiple `setState` calls may result in multiple renderings, one for each call (or actual changed values). For example, in the original code, when `foo` was `"string1"` before and then gets changed to `"string2"`, you may get two renderings - one in which `a` and `b` are both `true` and finally the one in which `a` is `false` and `b` is `true`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a single state member instead (probably with something enum-like, but I'll use a simple number here):

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
```

If you need `a`, `b`, etc. for convenience in the function code, you can set those up like this:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
// **IF** you really need discrete variables during the function's code
const a = value === 0;
const b = value === 1;
const c = value === 2;
const d = value === 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `useReducer`:

```js
import * as React from 'react';

const initialState = {
  a: false,
  b: false,
  c: false,
  d: false,
};

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET': {
      return {
        a: action.payload === 'string1',
        b: action.payload === 'string2',
        c: action.payload === 'string3',
        d: action.payload === 'string4',
      };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default function App() {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>State</h1>
      <p>A: {state.a ? 'true' : 'false'}</p>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'SET', payload: 'string1' })}>Set a</button>
      <p>B: {state.b ? 'true' : 'false'}</p>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'SET', payload: 'string2' })}>Set a</button>
      <p>C: {state.c ? 'true' : 'false'}</p>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'SET', payload: 'string3' })}>Set a</button>
      <p>D: {state.d ? 'true' : 'false'}</p>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'SET', payload: 'string4' })}>Set a</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-euclid-6sk3k